# Use MyEclipse to open a project in web browser, the URL has ''//'' in front the webapp's name

Tags: url, myeclipse

when I use MyEclipse to open a project in web browser, the URL has ''//'' in front the webapp's name like this "http://localhost:8080//portal/".
why there is a :8080//, I think it should be :8080/.
who can help me ,thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're on the latest release of MyEclipse, check the preferences page, MyEclipse/Project Facets/Web and the Context Root tab. If it has "//portal", change it to "/portal", if that's what you need.

If you're not using the latest release, you'll need to look for a similar setting elsewhere in the preferences or project properties.

Comment: thanks for your help, I checked the setting, the Context Root tab is "/portal",but the problem remain there.Is there something else ?

Comment: Sorry about that. Well, I'm not sure there's enough info to figure this out. Like the server you're trying to deploy to, the release of MyEclipse being used, whether portal is part of another project, any changes to configuration files (either project configuration or server configuration), etc.